# Starting Web Services and Rest on same port in embedded Jetty

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jetty

I had running on same port both SOAP Web Services and my REST api. This was using Spring 4.1.2 / CXF 2.7.15 / Jetty 8.1.16. Now I have upgraded my versions to Spring 4.2.3 / CXF 3.1.4 / Jetty 9.3.6. It seems that I can have either SOAP Web Services or REST on same port, depending on which is added in the code first during startup. How can I get them working again in the same time?

**UPDATE**

Example of the code that was working:

```
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine;
import org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext;
import my.package.app.DefaultApp;
import my.package.misc.jmx.JMXAgent;
import my.package.misc.xmpp.XmppManager;
import my.package.rest.standalone.JacksonJsonProvider;
import my.package.util.PropertyUtil;
import my.package.webservice.user.UserWs;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class StartApp extends DefaultApp {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartApp.class);
    private static boolean started;
    // TODO: move this to SPRING
    protected static ExecutorService startupExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    // setting DNS caching to 1 hour
    static {
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "3600");
    }

    private class ServiceStartTask implements Callable<Void> {
        private Endpoint endpoint;
        private String address;
        private int port;
        private String name;
        private Class implementor;
        private boolean startRest;
        private String packages;

        public ServiceStartTask(Endpoint endpoint, String address, int port, String name, Class implementor, boolean startRest, String packages) {
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
            this.address = address;
            this.port = port;
            this.name = name;
            this.implementor = implementor;
            this.startRest = startRest;
            this.packages = packages;
            log.debug("address = {} port = {} name = {} ", address, port, name);
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() {
            String baseUrl = "http://" + address + ":" + port + "/";
            String wsUrl = baseUrl + name;
            String restUrl = baseUrl + "rest";

            log.info("Export ws on: " + wsUrl);
            try {
                endpoint = Endpoint.create(DefaultApp.getBean(implementor));

                additionalJettySetup(endpoint, wsUrl, restUrl, implementor.getPackage().getName(), startRest, packages + ",my.package.rest.common");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("error publishing service " + wsUrl, e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Endpoint endpointUser;

    public StartApp() {
    }

    public void start() {
        String[] s = {};
        start(s);
    }


    public void start(String[] args) {
        if (started) {
            return;
        }

        earlyInit();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        registerShutdownHook();

        init();

        if (PropertyUtil.getPropertyBoolean("jmx.enabled")) {
            startJMX();
        }

        String address;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            address = "localhost";
        } else {
            address = args[0];
        }

        publishWebServices(address);

        log.debug("starting rest services");
        // separate jetty instance for additional rest services
        int restPort = PropertyUtil.getPropertyInteger("rest.port");
        startRest(address, restPort, "my.package.rest.standalone");
        log.debug("rest services started");


        started = true;

        final long startupTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }


    /**
     * Setup all Jetty properties that cannot be configured in spring xml.
     *
     * @param endpoint
     * @param restUrl
     * @param domain
     * @param startRest
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected synchronized void additionalJettySetup(Endpoint endpoint, String wsUrl, String restUrl, String domain, boolean startRest, String packages) throws IOException {
        if (endpoint instanceof EndpointImpl) {
            // finding Jetty Server object
            EndpointImpl endpointJetty = (EndpointImpl) endpoint;
            // loging interceptors needs to be added before endpoint.getServer call
            addInterceptors(endpointJetty);

            ServerImpl server = endpointJetty.getServer(wsUrl);
            if (endpointJetty.getServerFactory().getDestinationFactory().getDestination(server.getEndpoint().getEndpointInfo()) instanceof JettyHTTPDestination) {
                JettyHTTPDestination d = (JettyHTTPDestination) endpointJetty.getServerFactory().getDestinationFactory().getDestination(server.getEndpoint().getEndpointInfo());
                JettyHTTPServerEngine engine = (JettyHTTPServerEngine) d.getEngine();
                if (startRest) {
                    log.info("Also starting REST service at {}", restUrl);
                    setRestConfig(engine, packages);
                }
                // publishing and starting the server
                endpoint.publish(wsUrl);
                // finally server is found
                Server jetty = engine.getServer();
                addJettyMBeans(domain, jetty);

            }
        }
    }

    private void addInterceptors(EndpointImpl endpointJetty) {
        //adding some endpoint interceptors
    }

    /**
     * Sets REST configuration for an existing server
     *
     * @param engine
     * @param packages
     */
    private void setRestConfig(final JettyHTTPServerEngine engine, final String packages) {

        List<Handler> handlers = engine.getHandlers();
        ServletContextHandler root = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        setRestServletAndApplicationContext(root, packages, "/rest/*");

        handlers.add(root);
    }

    /**
     * Adds to JMX Jetty object that will be monitored.
     */
    protected void addJettyMBeans(String domain, Server jetty) {
        log.debug("creating MBeanContainer");
        MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
        mbContainer.setDomain(domain);
        jetty.getContainer().addEventListener(mbContainer);
        jetty.addBean(mbContainer);
        // Adding bean that we want to be exposed to JMX
        mbContainer.addBean(jetty.getConnectors()[0]);
        mbContainer.addBean(jetty);
        mbContainer.addBean(jetty.getThreadPool());
    }

    protected void startJMX() {
        try {
            JMXAgent.premain();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("JMX agent startup error", e);
        }
    }

    private void startRest(final String address, final int restPort, final String packages) {
        startupExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startRestfullServer(address, restPort, packages);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRestfullServer(final String address, final int restPort, final String packages) {
        log.info("Starting REST service at port {}", restPort);
        Server server = new Server(restPort);
        try {
            ServletContextHandler root = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
            setRestServletAndApplicationContext(root, packages + ",some.package", "/*");

            server.setHandler(root);
            server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
            server.setGracefulShutdown(1000);

            server.start();
            server.join();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
            try {
                server.stop();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                log.error("error", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setRestServletAndApplicationContext(ServletContextHandler root, String packages, String servletPath) {
        root.setContextPath("/");

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.packages("org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;" + packages);

        // using our custom mapping provider
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        // processing multipart
        resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

        resourceConfig.register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        resourceConfig.register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

        ServletContainer ss = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);

        ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(ss);


        root.addServlet(servletHolder, servletPath);
        setUpSwagger();
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.copyConfigurationFrom(getContext().getBeanFactory());

        // CORS filter to allow swagger to be used from Swagger UI on another host
        root.addFilter(CrossOriginFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST));

        /**
         * The trick is that Jersey expect WebApplication context and we need to mask our context as web context
         * so we create a WebApplicationContext and makes methods that Jersey uses to return from spring context.
         */
        final GenericWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext(beanFactory) {
            @Override
            public String[] getBeanNamesForType(Class<?> type) {
                return getParent().getBeanNamesForType(type);
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException {
                return getParent().getBean(name, requiredType);
            }

            @Override
            public <T> Map<String, T> getBeansOfType(Class<T> type) throws BeansException {
                return getParent().getBeansOfType(type);
            }
        };

        webApplicationContext.setServletContext(root.getServletContext());
        webApplicationContext.setParent(getContext());
        root.getServletContext().setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webApplicationContext);
        webApplicationContext.refresh();
    }

    private void setUpSwagger() {
        //settting up swagger
    }

    public void stop() {
        log.info("Stopping ALL WSs");

        getBean(XmppManager.class).send("Going off...!");

        if (endpointUser != null) {
            endpointUser.stop();
        }
    }

    private void registerShutdownHook() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.info("Shutdown hook for StartApp executed");
                StartApp.this.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    private void publishWebServices(String address) {
        int portUser = PropertyUtil.getPropertyInteger("webservice.user.port");
        List<ServiceStartTask> services = new ArrayList<>();
        services.add(publish(endpointUser, address, portUser, "user", UserWs.class, true, "rest.endpoint.package"));
        for (ServiceStartTask task : services) {
            task.call();
        }
    }

    private <T> ServiceStartTask publish(Endpoint endpoint, String address, int port, String name, Class<T> implementor, boolean startRest, String packages) {
        return new ServiceStartTask(endpoint, address, port, name, implementor, startRest, packages);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new StartApp().start(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error starting app!", e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Jetty engines declared in Spring:

```
<!-- Jetty parameters -->
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <!-- user -->
    <httpj:engine port="${webservice.user.port}">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="5"
                                   maxThreads="100"/>
        <httpj:connector>
            <beans:bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <beans:property name="port" value="${webservice.user.port}"/>
                <beans:property name="statsOn" value="false"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </httpj:connector>
        <httpj:handlers>
            <beans:bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
        </httpj:handlers>
        <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

Comment: There's not enough information to go on in this question.  What happens? what errors do you see?  how did you get it to work in Jetty 8?   What does each of those classes in your example belong to? A working example (complete with proper import statements) might help.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Here is more detailed look at what was working